# Splitting/breaking a long table from an input file

Tags: tables, input

I am input a file in my main latex file but the table (inputfiles contains a table) is too long to be on apage. How can I break it on two or main pages.

```
\usepackage{longtable} %%


\IfFileExists{file}{%
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\caption{Grenzwertverletzung [st]}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
st&  \input{file} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
}{}
```

[image]

Comment: \usepackage{longtable}

Comment: @  Eddy_Em, please see edited question

Comment: `\begin{longtable}` …  Just read its documentation!

Comment: http://users.sdsc.edu/~ssmallen/latex/longtable.html

Comment: What should I change?????????

Comment: remove `\begin{table}`, substitute `\begin{tabular}` to `\begin{longtable}` (also with `\end…`) and add headers & footers (like in example under link).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, using the `longtable` package looks like the way forward here. Standard LaTeX tables are box-like objects that cannot be spit across pages, so you need something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ll}
 Entry & Value \\
 1     & 123 \\
 2     & 456 \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

To deal with formatting, *etc.*, we will need a full example of what you want and probably some demo data too. (The use of `\input` shouldn't make any difference to the situation.)